# Object Arrary throwing error on element type on ReDim

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have been trying to assign value to an object array that is defined as follows...

```
Dim englishTextAry As Object(,) = New Object(,) {}
```

I am looping through a dataReader and trying to assign the values to this array with the following code....

```
While rdr.Read()
    Dim recID As String = rdr.Item(0)
    Dim dataVal As String = rdr.Item(1)

    ReDim Preserve englishTextAry(recID, dataVal)

End While
```

But the ReDim is throwing an error on dataVal not being an Integer.

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be doing a horrible number of ReDims for a non-small numbers of rows. You could use a Class to hold the id-value pairs and a list to hold them:

```
Module Module1

    Class IdValPair
        Property RecId As String
        Property DataVal As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim myItems As New List(Of IdValPair)
        '...
        While rdr.Read
            myItems.Add(New IdValPair With {.RecId = rdr.Item(0), .DataVal = rdr.Item(1)})
        End While

    End Sub

End Module
```

...and to answer your question, the ReDim statement takes numbers for the sizes to ReDim to.

Comment: How do I read the data back? I would have a variable named value, that would be equal to one of the recId in the class, I need the dataVal where value=recId.

Comment: You can use LINQ to query the data in the list, e.g. if there will be only one dataVal to be retrieved: Dim x = (From p In myItems Where p.DataVal = value Select p.RecId).First

Answer (score -1):

Look into the ArrayList object.  I usually use that for dynamically adding / getting values with a lot easier code than normal arrays.

Comment: `ArrayList` is deprecated. Don’t use it. The `System.Collections.Generic` namespace offers replacement.

Comment: Unless you're stuck with Visual Studio 2003, you'd want to use a generic List instead of an ArrayList.